# How do I transfer a list from python to an array in javascript using pyscript?

Tags: javascript, python, pyscript

**Problem:**

I am trying to transfer a list from python, x = [1,2,3,4], to an array in javascript with the same values, x = [1,2,3,4]. I want to use pyscript to do this.

I have tried using the following --> pyscript.interpreter.globals.get('x')

I can get this to work with simple values, x = 42. However when transferring a list, it packages it into a proxy object. I can't seem to unpackage it into a useful array in javascript. Console.log and inner.HTML calls show the whole value of x, but I can't iterate through the object, and I can't pull single values, such as x[2], which should return the value, 3.

**Things I've tried:**

I've tried using import js, and labeling the item as js.x to transport the list to javascript, but I still run into the whole proxy-object problem.

I've tried looking this up on stack overflow but couldn't find any similar questions. I tried looking up how to unpackage the proxy object, but I couldn't find any relevant information or instructions.

**Question:**

How can I unpackage this proxy object?

**Here's my code**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table Editor</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
        <body>
        <py-script>x = [1,2,3,4]</py-script>

        <button onclick="show_x_in_console()">show 'x' from Python in console.log</button>
        <button onclick="show_x_in_body()">show 'x' from Python in body</button>
        <script>
            function show_x_in_console(){
                console.log(`In Python right now, x = ${pyscript.interpreter.globals.get('x')}`)
            }
            function show_x_in_body(){
              var id1 = document.getElementById("id1")
              var id2 = document.getElementById("id2")
              var id3 = document.getElementById("id3")
              var x = pyscript.interpreter.globals.get('x')
              id1.innerHTML = x
              id2.innerHTML = typeof(x)
              id3.innerHTML = x[2]
            }
        </script>
  
      <p id="id1"></p>
      <p id="id2"></p>
      <p id="id3"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is what the page looks like. When I click the second button, it shows x[2] as undefined instead of 3.
[image: image of loaded page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the problem you're facing is because the way Python's list is being passed to JavaScript is not directly usable. You need to convert it to a JavaScript array before you can access its elements like you normally would in JavaScript. So you should change it to `Array.from()`.

Here is the updated function:

```
function show_x_in_body() {
  var id1 = document.getElementById("id1");
  var id2 = document.getElementById("id2");
  var id3 = document.getElementById("id3");
  var pyList = pyscript.interpreter.globals.get("x");
  
  // Convert Python list (pyList) to JS array here
  var x = Array.from(pyList);

  id1.innerHTML = x;
  id2.innerHTML = typeof(x);
  id3.innerHTML = x[2];
}
```

Try it and let me now the results! :)

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly!  (note, it needs to be var x = Array.from(pyList))

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread syntax to convert the Proxy to an array:

```js
var x = [...pyscript.interpreter.globals.get('x')];
```

Alternatively, use `.get` instead of bracket notation to access an element of the list by index:

```js
var x = pyscript.interpreter.globals.get('x');
id3.innerHTML = x.get(2);
```

Comment: See the code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/gwy5envx/

Comment: this is a good answer too for accessing individual elements. I suppose one could iterate through all the individual elements and add them to a new array as an alternative solution